# Lubuntu 16.04 not accepting connections from outside of LAN

Tags: networking, server, ssh, lubuntu, firewall

After two days of googling and searching askubuntu i decided to start a thread.

Here's my problem:

I recently exchanged my server (running Lubuntu 12.04 with ssh service and a game service) for a newer one (running Lubuntu 16.04). The network card stays the same, I built it in the new server. After setting up the new server with those two services I could only connect from inside the LAN. Everytime I tried connecting with my mobile data the connection timed out. GRC's [ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) shows the two ports i use as [Stealth](https://www.grc.com/su/portstatusinfo.htm), other ports as Closed.

Here's what I've tried:

- Connecting my old server again - both services worked, ShieldsUP shows the ports as Open, so Port forwarding and DNS resolving can't be the problem.
- disabling ufw (is there another sort of firewall which could be blocking ports?)
- enabling ufw and allowing the Ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, the problem was just a faulty routing table. It preferred the wired network card over the Wi-fi card i was actually using.

so

```
route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.2 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev enp0s10
```

did it for me.

Comment: I would mark this as answered, but askubuntu won't let me for the next two days.
I won't delete the thread though, might be helpful for someone.